# Stream isn't closing after sending file

Tags: java

Excuse me my understanding of streams is slowly building.

I initally tried to stream a music file over to my client but that didn't work out so I moved transferring the entire file via bytes then saving it at the client side. The problem is the input stream is still receiving bytes and so won't break out of the while loop (Where I want to play the song)

Below is part of my client code:

```
//This is part of a task that carries this out (Part of a UI application)
@Override
protected Void call()
{
    try(Socket socket = new Socket(host,portNumber); 
        ObjectOutputStream toServer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream fromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))
    {
        //Client requests a song from the server (song is a String)
        toServer.writeUTF(".Music."+song);
        toServer.flush();

        //Create a new file (tempSong is a string)
        File test = new File(tempSong);
        test.createNewFile();

        //New file writer
        BufferedOutputStream bOS = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(test));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int current;

        /** 
         * Read the bytes from the server and write the file
         * The file is written and I can play it (externally)
         * but the while loop doesn't break after writting the file
         */
        while ((current = fromServer.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            bOS.write(buffer, 0 , current);
        }

        System.out.println("Finished writing");

        bOS.close();

        /**
         * down here a method is ran to play the file
         * but it never happen because the task is still in the while loop
         */
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

below is in the server where the server reads the message and sends the file

```
/** This is part of a task and the main call area */
@Override
public Void call ()
{
    try
    {
        //Setup I/O
        toClient = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream fromClient = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        while(!socket.isClosed())
        {
            //If server has received a message
            if(fromClient.available() > 0)
            {
                //Reads message and objects from client
                String input = fromClient.readUTF();

                if (input.contains(".Music"))
                {
                    findMusic(input, toClient);
                }

                /**
                 * more else IFs
                 */
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
/**
 * this method is part of the task discussed above
 */
//The method that is called
private void findMusic(String input, ObjectOutputStream toClient)
{
    logoff();
    String[] names = input.split("[.]");
    clientManagerTemp.logger("Someone request song: " + names[2] + ".mp3");

    File musicFile = AudioUtil.getSoundFile("src/Resources/Songs/" + names[2]+ ".mp3");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) musicFile.length()];

    try(BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(musicFile)))
    {
        bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

        clientManagerTemp.logger("Sending " + "src/Resources/Songs/" + names[2]+ ".mp3" + "(" + buffer.length + " bytes)");
        //write the file to the client

        toClient.write(buffer,0, buffer.length);
        toClient.flush();

        clientManagerTemp.logger("Finished sending");

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

So as you can see the server sends the file fine and my client receives it. It just won't stop the while loop. Can someone explain why? So I can get a better understanding of how streaming bytes over sockets work

**EDIT 
When the client receives the file it can be played even after closing the client and server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send the file-length to the client, with this information the client knows when to exit the loop.

**Server**

```
private void findMusic(String input, ObjectOutputStream toClient)
{
    logoff();
    String[] names = input.split("[.]");
    clientManagerTemp.logger("Someone request song: " + names[2] + ".mp3");

    File musicFile = AudioUtil.getSoundFile("src/Resources/Songs/" + names[2]+ ".mp3");
    int fileLength = (int) musicFile.length();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileLength];

    try(BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(musicFile)))
    {
        bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

        clientManagerTemp.logger("Sending " + "src/Resources/Songs/" + names[2]+ ".mp3" + "(" + buffer.length + " bytes)");
        //write the file to the client

        toClient.writeInt(fileLength);
        toClient.write(buffer,0, buffer.length);
        toClient.flush();

        clientManagerTemp.logger("Finished sending");

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int current;
int fileLength = fromServer.readInt();

while ( fileLength > 0 && (current = fromServer.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(4096,fileLength))) > 0)
{
    bOS.write(buffer, 0 , current);
    fileLength -= current;
}
```

Comment: @0x1C1B Your solution was useful but I really appreciate the example @devpuh gave. Just curious why do you make the length vary? i'm talking about the `Math.min(4096, fileLength)`. From my understanding the `.min` method find the smallest number between the two

Comment: @Lucky38i The `.min` will ensure that you only read the size of the file and don't exceed the buffer-size. For example when the file size is only 100 bytes you only need to read 100 bytes and not 4096 bytes. (You could create a buffer which size is the file-size, but this will only consume a lot of memory)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the nature of the read method, seen here [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#read()). This method will block until there is data, so your loop will never end. Now the reason for this is because you never close the stream on the server end, you just flush it, which forces a send of all the data currently in the buffer, but will not close the stream. If you call .close() on the stream from the server side then that should exit the while loop on the client side and continue to your playing code.

I haven't tested this, but from the documentation and a brief look at your code, that seems to be the issue.

Comment: `and will always be greater than 0` Strictly this sentence is not correct. You are right. the `read()` is the culprit here but it's due to it's behaviour in a when encountering an 'empty stream'. The returned value is not 0. It's just simply stuck and never returns. Unless the stream is closed.

Comment: @L.Spillner Ah yea, technically incorrect, i'll edit it out now to reflect that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't close the connection (server side), there will not be an end-of-file/end-of-stream and your client side will run the loop forever, unless you configured a read timeout.

If you won't to close the loop automatically after sending the file is finished, send the count of bytes (size of file) first to client and then the file itself. This makes it possible to read only a exact number of bytes on client side and close the connection when finished.
Alternative you can send a special sequence and check for them at client side to mark the end of stream.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you program is stuck is due to the behaviour of `ObjectInputStream.read()`. This method is **blocking** until it has read some data or the stream is closed. Since you never close the stream the 2nd condition will never be met. So there is only option 1. To return when data arrived. Unfortuenatly there is no way to recognize the end of a file unless you define it yourself e.g. by sending a unique sequenz or something that you can recognize to **break** the while loop.

**Example:**

```
while ((current = fromServer.read(buffer)) > 0)
{  
      // example value 42 could be anything else as well
      if(current == -42) 
      {
          break;
      }
      bOS.write(buffer, 0 , current);
}
```

The downside of this is, that your data could also contain this special value so you gotta think about different possibilities e.g memorize the sequence up to 3 values and compare them to an 'interrupt sequence'.